# angular scripts not working while ajax callback

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, accordion

I've a page, where I've defined all the angular coding for accordion.
Now, I'm loading that page content using ajax.

**My angular page content**

```js
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

function AccordionDemoCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.groups = [{
        DivisionId: 1,
        Division: '.Net',
        items: [{
            'Id': 1,
                'Name': 'Manikishore',
                'Division': '.Net'
        }, {
            'Id': 2,
                'Name': 'Santosh',
                'Division': '.Net'
        }, {
            'Id': 2,
                'Name': 'Prakash',
                'Division': '.Net'
        }]
    }, {
        DivisionId: 2,
        Division: 'Design',
        items: [{
            'Id': 19,
                'Name': 'Mahesh',
                'Division': 'Design'
        }, {
            'Id': 20,
                'Name': 'Hareen',
                'Division': 'Design'
        }]
    }];
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <script src="JS/test.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
            <accordion>
                <accordion-group heading="{{group.Division}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
                    <accordion-heading> <span ng-click="opened(group, $index)">
                        {{group.Division}}
                    </span>

                    </accordion-heading>
                    <ul class="ulaccordionscroll" style="height:250px;overflow-y:auto;">
                        <li ng-repeat="item in group.items">{{item['Name']}}</li>
                    </ul>
                </accordion-group>
            </accordion>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Actually, If I run this script, it's working fine.
But in my case, I'm loading this page into another page using ajax on a button click.

**Master page**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.3.0.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

 <a onclick="redirect()">click</a>
 <div id="maindiv" style="background-color:#eee;padding:50px;"></div>

<script>
        function redirect() {
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Default.aspx/',
                type: "GET",
                success: function (response) {
                    debugger;
                    $("#maindiv").empty();
                    $('#maindiv').html(response);
                },
                error: function (err) { debugger; }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

But the angular code is not working.
I've made a sample video describing my error.
[Sample Video Link](https://uandmestaging.com/samplefiles/angularproblem.swf)

I've followed this [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/B3LC1X?p=preview) to get angular accordion

**Note** : Unfortunately, the code snippet is not working because of the `test.js` reference

Comment: I think the problem has nothing to do with the accordion. I suggest you reduce the template being loaded via ajax to a very simple ng-model binding to illustrate the problem.

Comment: By looking at your code, I didn't see any code that register your AccordionDemoCtrl function to be a controller for Angular. It should have angular.module('plunker').controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', AccordionDemoCtrl);

Comment: you should use Angular way to do Ajax call.

Comment: @RealSteel, your ajax result is an html and it was not compiled by angular. You need compile your result before append it to your current page.

Comment: It will not work like this, you need to bootstrap Angular application manually after you insert content in DOM.

Comment: @dfsq: I've already tried calling this angular script `angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);` in `setTimeout` but even then it's not working :(

Comment: @Michelem : actually my whole application is in knockoutjs. so, I've used ajax to call the pages and load the content.
now, I need to implement angularjs only for this particular requirement.
so, I cannot use angular way to do ajax call.

Comment: @RealSteel `angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);` is not manual bootstrapping. You need to bootstrap application **manually** by providing application root.

Comment: @dfsq:Thanks man!!! It worked for me.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By @dfsq Comment : we need to bootstrap application manually by providing application root.

I've done the following changes and it worked for me!!!

```
angular.module('plunker', [])
      .controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
          $scope.groups = [
      {
          DivisionId: 1, Division: '.Net',
          items: [{ 'Id': 1, 'Name': 'Manikishore', 'Division': '.Net' },
           { 'Id': 2, 'Name': 'Santosh', 'Division': '.Net' },
           { 'Id': 2, 'Name': 'Santosh', 'Division': '.Net' },
           { 'Id': 2, 'Name': 'Santosh', 'Division': '.Net' }]
      },
      {
          DivisionId: 2, Division: 'Design',
          items: [{ 'Id': 19, 'Name': 'Mahesh', 'Division': 'Design' },
            { 'Id': 20, 'Name': 'Hareen', 'Division': 'Design' }]
      }
          ];
      }]);


angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['plunker', 'ui.bootstrap']);
});
```